How to avoid areas overlapping in Godot?
I'm making a top-down game where the player can drag the characters on the screen, and I'm wondering how I should avoid the player from dragging a character into another one.
I've tried this code that was run every frame for the character that was being dragged to get that character out of the other hitboxes :
if distance_keeping:
    while $BigHitbox.get_overlapping_areas():
        for i in $BigHitbox.get_overlapping_areas():
            position += (position - i.get_parent().position).normalized()

However, as it turns out, get_overlapping_areas only updates each physics step, so it gets stuck in an infinite loop and I didn't find any way to manually update the collisions.
I've thought about somehow calculating how much the character should move in order to get out of the other character's hitbox, but even if I did that, moving out of a character's hitbox can easily cause to move into another character's hitbox, and I still wouldn't know about it because get_overlapping_areas wouldn't update till the next physics update.
I've also thought about applying phyisics to the characters and use move_and_slide in the direction where the mouse is moved but then it wouldn't go through characters at all - even after it could without it ending up in another hitbox.

You are using drag as a mechanism to move your MC normally? Or just to pick him/her up and place her somewhere else? For the former, sounds like you need to do some specialized hit testing against your scene. For the second, let the user let go wherever, and if the target is not a valid spot, return the MC to the original location.

@Dúthomhas I'm using the drag mechanic as the main way of moving the characters. The game would be a turn based strategy game where positioning is crucial so I don't want to just send back the character because it's 1 pixel inside another character's htibox, that's why I'd like to move them away from the characters that the dragged character is touching til it's not touching anything anymore. The problem is that I don't think I can update the collisions manually. Will I have to write my own collision detection if I want to check multiple times a frame or is there a simpler way?

That works. When you let go, just move your character as few pixels as needed to avoid touching anything. Even if you use a brute-force expanding circle to find that spot (and give up after expanding a reasonable amount) you shouldn’t have any noticeable delay.
